# Image lagging while blitting on top of mouse rect

Tags: python, windows, image, pygame, blit

I'm trying to build a simple version of an aim trainer using pygame and have decided to change the original mouse pointer to a crosshair (an image). When testing if the image has been blitted on the mouse rect I noticed that the image is significantly lagging behind the position of the mouse.

I have tried to tamper with the FPS of the game by setting the `clock.tick()` to different integers. Tried loading the images in a different part of the code. However nothing seems to change the lag.

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics ## screen size getter so that theres no need to use coordinates, can be run on multiple resolutions

screen_width = GetSystemMetrics(0) ## get screen width and hieght
screen_hieght = GetSystemMetrics(1)


class GameWindow():

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
    pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
    caption = pygame.display.set_caption("Alex's FPS Trainer")
    main_screen_font = pygame.font.SysFont('consolas', 100)

    main_screen_background = pygame.image.load("fps_background.jpg") ## loading images
    xhair_image = pygame.image.load("crosshair.png")

    def __init__(self):
        self.background = pygame.transform.scale(GameWindow.main_screen_background, (screen_width, screen_hieght))
        self.title = self.main_screen_font.render("Alex's FPS Aim Trainer", 1,  (245, 66, 66))
        self.run()

    def blit(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.background, (0, 0))
        self.screen.blit(self.title, (screen_width/2 - screen_width/3.5, screen_hieght/5))
        self.screen.blit(GameWindow.xhair_image, (pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0] - 13.5,pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1] - 13.5)) ## centres mouse

    def createButton(self):
        pass

    def run(self):
        run = True


        while run:
            pygame.time.Clock().tick(120)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: ## temporary quit key
                        run = False
                if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN: ## detect clicks
                    print("Mouse pressed")

            self.blit()
            pygame.display.update()

        pygame.quit()

GameWindow = GameWindow()
```

I was hoping that the image would follow the mouse without lag since it is important for the crosshair in an aim trainer to follow the mouse well.

Comment: No one can run your code to reproduce the problem without the `fps_background.jpg` and `crosshair.png` image files. Please [edit] your question and add them.

Comment: you could try to use `your_image = your_image.convert()` to change image's pixel format to screen's pixel format ([pygame.Surface.convert](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert)), It should blit images faster. You blit title always in the same place on background so you could blit it once on background and later blit one image less.

Comment: @martineau how could i add the images so that everyone can use them. Another solution would be to use any image found on the internet. It doesnt have to be the one i used since its only a background and a random crosshair

Comment: Alex: True, but why should everyone working on your question have to do that? When you edit your question there's a tool icon you can click on to add an image.

Comment: @furas thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. :(

Comment: `blit()` gives `Rect` with area which was changed and `.display.update()` can get list with these areas to update only these parts. It should need less time to update screen because you don't need to blit background again but I never tried it - it may need prevous screen to copy old areas.

Comment: PyGame is based on SDL 1.2 which is very old. They work on PyGame 2 which will use SLD 2.x and maybe it will work faster. There is also PySDL2 and [Arcade](http://arcade.academy/pygame_comparison.html) which use PySDL2, Or maybe you have to use PyOpenGL, eventually rewrite it all with C/C++ and SDL :) OR mayb you need only set [different driver](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.init) for PyGame

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to change the mouse cursor by [`win32api.SetCursor()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__SetCursor_meth.html):

```py
win32api.SetCursor(cursor)
```

A cursor can be loaded by [`win32gui.LoadImage()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__LoadImage_meth.html) from a `.cur` file:

```py
cursor = win32gui.LoadImage(0, "cursor.cur", win32con.IMAGE_CURSOR,
                            0, 0, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)
```

or from an [`.ico`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format)) file.

```py
cursor = win32gui.LoadImage(0, path + "cursor.ico", win32con.IMAGE_ICON,
                            0, 0, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)
```

See also [Cursors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/cursors) and [`LoadImage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea).

To avoid flickering it is important to make the *"pygame"* cursor invisible by [`pygame.mouse.set_visible()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_visible)

```py
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

Set the cursor immediately before [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) respectively [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip), to make it *"visible"* and to give *pygame* no chance to *"hide"* it.

```py
win32api.SetCursor(cursor)
pygame.display.update()
```

See the example application:

```py
import pygame
import win32api, win32gui, win32con

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

cursor = win32gui.LoadImage(0, path + "cursor.ico", win32con.IMAGE_ICON,
                            0, 0, win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(120)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    win32api.SetCursor(cursor)
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I think easier solution is hiding OS cursor, but this is better solution :)

Comment: I had the OS cursos still visible so that people could see the lag

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks for the answer. This did solve the initial problem of replacing the cursor with another image and avoiding lag. However new problems arose that I will be trying to solve. The new cursor flickers a lot from some reason. It also doesnt move as expected unless i have pygame.mouse.set_visible() set to true which is wierd.

Comment: Try `pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)` `win32api.SetCursor(cursor)` `pygame.display.update()` `pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)`